# case esac structure in bash, "special characters"

Tags: bash

Good day,

I was wondering how to use a special character, "-", in a case esac structure:

```
case $var in
    [1234567890] )
        -----commands-----
    -)
        -----commands-----
esac
```

when I use this structure, I get:

```
line 59: syntax error near unexpected token `)'
line 59: `          - )'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `-` (an ordinary hyphen) is not a special character in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to end the previous command block with a double semicolon.

```
case $var in
    [1234567890] )
        -----commands----- ;;
    -)
        -----commands----- ;;
esac
```